# Joomla pages not changing in a frontend after save

Tags: joomla

I have a following problem: i made some change in admin area (updated existed page). That page was under lock, so i removed locking. I made some text changes and it seems that server saves them. But in a frontend page are not changing at all. I removed cache files, pushed clear cache, even disabled cache module, but without luck.

Comment: Might check if you have require captcha for frontend editing required in CONTENT->ARTICLES->Options.  I had an issue with that where the error wasn't visible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that pages, which was not editable, was created with HG Static Content Module. So I found this modules in modules admin section and changed them.